# Django 1.5 transaction middleware : do you need to use it?

Tags: django, django-middleware

we have this super weird issue happening with postgres that only happens on random requests. We get an InterfaceError: connection already closed which seems to be being thrown by the TransactionMiddleware. This was causing random 500 pages for the end-user.

Removing TransactionMiddleware seems to solve all our issues however I am quite scared about what this might actually do. If you remove TransactionMiddleware will it in anyway endanger data integrity via dirty reads/writes or cause any other issues?

I have googled high and low to try and figure out why TransactionMiddleware is throwing this error but nothing seems too relevant.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: I don't know the direct answer to your question, but I should say that the whole Django 1.5 transaction scheme is questionable and thus it's been replaced entirely in 1.6.  1.6 transactions are/will be much better.

Comment: Obvious question about your situation - do you have some middleware that accesses database after transaction is closed? tracebacks and other technical information would be useful, for understand the situation. Is this bug in django already tracker?

Comment: Thanks @singer. I will double check if any middleware does anything db related but I dont belive it does.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester thanks, yeah it looks way better. Can you get by without using it in 1.5? Not using it solved all our 500s but I am really nervous about data integrity now

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.  I am using 1.5 with transaction middleware and Postgres and we have not had trouble (though our app is still development and we have not stress-tested it yet).  I'm interested in your problem but I don't have any insight.  Sorry!